# TimeSpan Time Calculation, Minutes - ho to convert time span to int

Tags: c#

I have the folowing code,

now the question is what is the best way to preform this:

also take in notice the "minAdd" can pass 60, meaning 90min add (an hour an half etc)

thanks,

```
        int minAdd = Convert.ToInt16(txtMinAdd.text);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime nextEvent = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minAdd);
        TimeSpan diff = now - nextEvent;
        if (diff > minAdd) -------------- PROBLEM HERE
        {
            //act here
        }
```

Comment: Use diff.TotalMinutes. And please, read the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) before asking a question.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: As noted by Reed, the code you've shown is pretty pointless. I assume you actually want to get `nextEvent` from somewhere else.

I suspect you just want:

```
if (diff.TotalMinutes > minAdd)
{
}
```

Or you could use:

```
TimeSpan minTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToInt16(txtMinAdd.text));
...
if (diff > minTimeSpan)
{
}
```

Comment: diff is based on the DateTime generated - there is no reason for the check at all...

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Hadn't spotted that. I suspect the OP hasn't given representative code. Will edit to mention that.

Comment: My guess is the OP is trying (or needing) to schedule a timer, but doesn't know it...

Answer (score 1):

Since `diff` is based on `nextEvent`, which is based exactly on `minAdd`, there is no reason for this check - it will never be true.

Also, in your code, `diff` will always be negative if `minAdd` is positive, as you're subtracting a future event (`nextEvent`) from `DateTime.Now`.

If you are trying to schedule an event to occur at a point in time, you may want to consider using a `Timer`, and scheduling the timer to occur at some point in time based on the event time:

```
DateTime nextEvent = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minAdd);
TimeSpan diff = nextEvent - DateTime.Now;

// Schedule a timer to occur here
someTimer.Interval = diff.TotalMilliseconds; // Timer intervals are typically in ms
```